# Count how many duplicate and unique values I have in my array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array (size=6)
0 => 
     array (size=1)

     'test' => string 'AQHRmVBW7uTgObjnzkqrp' (length=30)  

1 =>  array (size=1)
     'test' => string 'AQHRmU8HooJPnCKUfkGLD' (length=30)   
2 => 
     array (size=1)

     'test' => string 'AQHRmU7+BdwM7pmpzEKew' (length=30)   
3 => 
     array (size=1)
     'test' => string 'AQHRmU74sTU6YP4GsEee8' (length=30)   
4 => 
     array (size=1)
     'test' => string 'AQHRmOqQAoHUgxj7T0et8' (length=30)   
5 => 
     array (size=1)
     'test' => string 'AQHRmOqQAoHUgxj7T0et8' (length=30)
```

Now I want to count how many even values there are in my array and how many uneven I have.

As you can see the last two results are the same in the array and the other 4 are all unique. So I want my final result to be:

```
even: 2
uneven: 4
```

Comment: Well first I would flatten the array to a one dimensional array and then go through each unique value and check if it exists a second time in the array or not.

Comment: i took this step to flatten, where the array above is $org_array->                             $flatarray = (array_values($org_array));
var_dump($flatarray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
     if(!isset($results[$value['test']])) $results[$value['test']]=0;
     $results[$value['test']]++;
}

//count even and uneven
$uneven = 0;
$even = 0;
foreach($results as $key => $count)
{
    if($count>1) $even += $count;
    else $uneven++;
}

echo 'Even: '.$even.'<br>';
echo 'Uneven: '.$uneven.'<br>';
```

Comment: Its shows even 1 (false) and uneven 4 (true). I think it shows 1 because code test for if one result look like another result (could that be it?). No matter what thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's our array:

```
$testArr = array(
    array('test' => 'AQHRmVBW7uTgObjnzkqrp'),
    array('test' => 'AQHRmU8HooJPnCKUfkGLD'),
    array('test' => 'AQHRmU7+BdwM7pmpzEKew'),
    array('test' => 'AQHRmU74sTU6YP4GsEee8'),
    array('test' => 'AQHRmOqQAoHUgxj7T0et8'),
    array('test' => 'AQHRmOqQAoHUgxj7T0et8'),
);
```

Now let's have some fn with it:

```
//First, let's flatten it
$flattenArr = array_column($testArr, 'test');
//And let's count values
$valsArr = array_count_values($flattenArr);

//Now filter elements that have only one occurrence
$unevenArr = array_filter($valsArr, function($val) {
    return $val==1;
});

//So now we can simply count this array to get "uneven" count...
$uneven = count($unevenArr);
//...and the rest is even
$even = count($testArr) - $uneven;
```

And let's see what we have:

```
echo "Even: {$even}<br/>"; //2
echo "Uneven {$uneven}";   //4
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to flatten your array to a one dimensional array by calling [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) with each subArray as argument with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Imagine it like this:

```
$flatten = array_merge($subArrayOne, $subArrayTwo /* , ... */);
```

Then you can count all values in the array with [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), loop through that array and create your expected output.

Code

```
<?php

    $arr = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $arr);
    $result = ["duplicates" => 0, "unique" => 0];

    foreach(array_count_values($arr) as $v => $count){
        if($count == 1)
            $result["unique"] += $count;
        else
            $result["duplicates"] += $count;
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [duplicates] => 4
    [unique] => 3
)
```